# Cannot query rows larger than 100MB limit

Tags: google-bigquery

Trying to update/insert (500k rows in a single struct array) records in the struct column. It throws the below error shown in the screenshot. Below is the query

```
insert into  test_dataset.hierarchy 
select create_date_time,update_date_time,name,
ARRAY_AGG(struct(  id,dba_name,  dba_address1,  dba_address2,  dba_city,  dba_state, dba_country,  dba_postal_code,  dba_fax_number,  dba_primary_phone_number,  dba_secondary_phone_number, dba_email,
[struct( attribute_name, attribute_value)] as  attribute_array)) as m_array  
from test_dataset.temp    
group by 1,2,3;
```

[Error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXAPs.png)
[Error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGhQH.png)

Need help on this issue.

Comment: There is 100 MB limit. Is it possible to select with the column create_date_time only part of the dataset. This could give you the chance to do insert over several queries.

Comment: Hi Samuel, thanks for your reply. But there are many more columns that I have not given in examples. so I need all those columns.

Answer (score 4):

To use array_agg you have the limitation of 100mb per line.
During group by, one or some of your lines grouped by 1,2,3 are exceeding this limit.

This usually happens with null values or some big groups that are usually not expected.
Also, keep in mind, the more columns you add, the heavier the line gets.

A way to solve this problem is breaking your group by into smaller groups.
Lets say you have
1.create_date_time 5 distinct registers,
2.update_date_time 10 distinct registers,
3.name 30million distinct registers.

Considering an equal distribution:
Group by 1 (6 million names per line)
Group by 2 (3 million names per line)
Group by 3 (1 name per line)

You can use group by with more columns, to make one big line into 4-5 smaller ones, this will drastically reduce the line size.